# Unable to display map even after having a billing account and a project linked

Tags: javascript, dictionary, display

I am unable to display the map. I have a billing account linked with my project and have enabled maps javascript API and used the generated API as a value of KEY parameter.`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <title>Contact Me</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="menu-btn">
        <div class="btn-line"></div>
        <div class="btn-line"></div>
        <div class="btn-line"></div>
      </div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <div class="menu-branding">
          <div class="portrait"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/dist/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/dist/about.html" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/dist/work.html" class="nav-link">My Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item current">
            <a href="/dist/contact.html" class="nav-link">How To Reach Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="contact">
      <h1 class="lg-heading">Contact <span class="text-secondary">Me</span></h1>
      <h2 class="sm-heading">This is how you can reach me...</h2>
      <div class="boxes">
        <div>
          <span class="text-secondary">Email: </span>abc@gmail.com
        </div>
        <div><span class="text-secondary">Phone: </span>9168439890</div>
      </div>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </main>

    <footer id="main-footer">
      Copyright &copy; 2020
    </footer>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my-api-key>&callback=initMap"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error which I am getting is:
*You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at `https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable` Learn more at `https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started`*

Comment: Maybe not the greatest idea to post your api key here?

Comment: @mplungjan anyone who can read source code can see it on OP's website. He hopefully has limited it to his domain and ip adresses only.